# material ui usestyles deprecated - do i need to change code

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, usestyles

I'm a bit confused on material ui v5.5.2 on how to useStyles().  This website says deprecated but if so how do you still use this?

https://mui.com/styles/basics/
⚠️ @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore, deprecated in v5. If you don't want to have both emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.

It says something about @mui/system but don't quite understand.

this is my old code.  should it be changing all of this?

```
const drawerWidth = 200; //240

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => {
return {
page: {
  background: "#f1f1f1",
  width: "100%",
  // padding: useTheme().spacing(3),
},
// drawer: {
//   width: drawerWidth,
//   backgroundColor: "red",
// },
drawerPaper: {
  width: drawerWidth,
},
root: {
  display: "flex",
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should if you're going to update MUI framework over time and/or use React 18 in strict mode. Please see [here](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/)

> @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.

Moreover they say that the new approach is better in performance and size (but I didn't test that yet), but see some performance measurements here [MUI System](https://mui.com/system/basics/)

I'm currently in the same situation and I'm going to study how to migrate everything to the new MUI system and [Emotion](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#emotion). See [here](https://networksynapse.net/development/mui-v5-material-with-emotion/) for an example on how to migrate from makeStyles to MUI v5 with Emotion.